# Получить название упавшего теста используя onTestFailure

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Собственно, можно ли в классе, который имплементирует интерфейс ITestListener, при помощи метода onTestFailure получить имя теста(метода) который упал?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл:

```
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult res) {
    System.out.println(res.getMethod().getMethodName());
}
```